# List comprehension in Python outputs None for function string evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, jupyter-notebook, list-comprehension

Trying to pass a list in Python through a function I have defined, however when I run the code I get 'None' as the output.

For reproducibility I'll use a simple example in which I want to make all words in a string uppercase.

```
def upcase(x):
    print(x.upper())

upcase("word")
```

This of course gives:

```
WORD
```

But now, if I attempt to apply my function to an entire string, as in the following:

```
randoms = ['chicken', 'window', 'carpet', 'lampshade', 'crosswalk']

randoms_upcased = [upcase(x) for x in randoms]
print(randoms)
print(randoms_upcased)
```

I get:

```
CHICKEN
WINDOW
CARPET
LAMPSHADE
CROSSWALK
['chicken', 'window', 'carpet', 'lampshade', 'crosswalk']
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Whereas the output I desire is this.

```
['chicken', 'window', 'carpet', 'lampshade', 'crosswalk']
['CHICKEN', 'WINDOW', 'CARPET', 'LAMPSHADE', 'CROSSWALK']
```

Is this possible? Any help gratefully receieved.

Comment: your function is only printing the output, not returning it. A python function without a return statement always returns None

Comment: Your function returns `None`, that is why your list-comprehension produces a list with all `None`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your upcase function prints out the result, but it doesn't return anything. Since you aren't specifying a return value, it defaults to returning `None`. You'll want to add an explicit return:

```
def upcase(x):
    x = x.upper()
    print(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the function upcase(s) is made to just print the string s in uppercase but it does not return anything. It should work if you return the uppercase string from the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the string you are printing.

This should work:

```
def upcase(x):
    return (x.upper())
```

Answer (score 1):

First store result in another list(`z`) then return (`z`) in the function:

```
def upcase(x):
    z = ([y.upper() for y in x])
    return z
l1 = ['chicken', 'window', 'carpet', 'lampshade', 'crosswalk']
upcase(l1)
```

output:

```
['CHICKEN', 'WINDOW', 'CARPET', 'LAMPSHADE', 'CROSSWALK']
```